# Is there a way to get rid of the installed modules tree after running npm install?

Tags: npm, npm-install

[image: Installed modules tree]

^

I want to get rid of this tree of modules since it clutters up our logs. Is there a way to do that but still keep potential deprecation warnings or errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install --depth=0` (it will narrow it down)

It seems like `--quiet` and `--silent` aren't working (An issue was opened on the npm repo: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2040 )